# jQuery how to display image loader on click of image thumbnail

Tags: jquery

I have written a jquery code for image gallery where there is a 1 large image and 4 small thumbnails. Need to display loader on the large image when clicking on small thumbnails.

please check with below working code.

```js
  $('.img1 a').click(function(e){
                             var title = $(this).attr('title');
                              var y = 1; while(y <= 4) {

         if(title == "img"+y){
  e.preventDefault();
   $(".bg4").attr('src',"http://hmsholidays.fluidux.in/wp-content/uploads/world/big-img"+y+".jpg").fadeIn();
    if(y == 1){
        $('.text-info4').text('Lion Park - South Africa');
    }
    if(y == 2){
        $('.text-info4').text('Bayworld - South Africa');
    }
    if(y == 3){
        $('.text-info4').text('Victoria Falls - South Africa ');
    }
    if(y == 4){
        $('.text-info4').text('South Africa Coach Holidays & Tours');
    }
         }

     y++; }
                              });
```

```html
 <img src="http://hmsholidays.fluidux.in/wp-content/uploads/world/big-img1.jpg" class="bg4" alt="">

 <ul class="cs-thumb-list img1">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="img1"><img src="http://hmsholidays.fluidux.in/wp-content/uploads/world/thumb-img1.jpg"
                                        alt=""></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="img2"><img src="http://hmsholidays.fluidux.in/wp-content/uploads/world/thumb-img2.jpg"
                                        alt=""></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="img3"><img src="http://hmsholidays.fluidux.in/wp-content/uploads/world/thumb-img3.jpg"
                                        alt=""></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" title="img4"><img src="http://hmsholidays.fluidux.in/wp-content/uploads/world/thumb-img4.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://hmsholidays.fluidux.in/wp-content/themes/hmsHolidays/js/jquery.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause your images are small size, even if you put a "loading" you will not see it.

You can test it with a timeout (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

but if you want a real "onLoadImage -> ChangeImage" check this plugin:
https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

For the loading state I use font awesome.

```
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
```

See the example in this page: http://fontawesome.io/examples/

So the logical programing is:

```
onClickImage
{
    ActualImage.Hide
    LoadingIco.Show

    SetTimeOut(2 seconds) //for development, but change for WaitForImages() plugin function
    {
        LoadingIco.Hide
        ClickedImage.Show 
    }
}
```

To center the fontAwesome icon use basic CSS:

```
#ParentOfTheIco{
    display: block;
    width: 100%; //Any width
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
#parent{
border:1px solid black;
height: 20px;
padding: 20px;
}
#loading_ico{
border:1px solid red;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="loading_ico">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, remember "break" the code and start another time the loading function if, while loading and image, the user clicks on another one.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add hidden gif img and show it with thumbnail click then hide when the big image is ready like

```
$("#loader").show();

$("#bigImage").ready(function(){
  $("#hide").show();
});
```

and place it with some css style like

```
#loader{
  //According to your style
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  left:50%;
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying is when I click on every small thumbnails at same time want to display loader and when background big images loads, the loader automatically hides and display big image

Comment: Okay, let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.img1 a').click(function(e){
  $(".loading_img").show();
  
  var title = $(this).attr('title');
  var y = 1; while(y <= 4) {
   if(title == "img"+y){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".bg4").attr('src',"http://hmsholidays.fluidux.in/wp-content/uploads/world/big-img"+y+".jpg").fadeIn();
    if(y == 1){
     $('.text-info4').text('Lion Park - South Africa');
    }
    if(y == 2){
     $('.text-info4').text('Bayworld - South Africa');
    }
    if(y == 3){
     $('.text-info4').text('Victoria Falls - South Africa ');
    }
    if(y == 4){
     $('.text-info4').text('South Africa Coach Holidays & Tours');
    }
   }
   y++; 
  }
  setTimeout(function() { $(".loading_img").hide(); }, 2000);
 });
})
```

```css
.loading_img {
  display:none;
 }
 
 .main_img{
  position:relative;
 }
 .loader {
  background-color: transparent;
  left: 23%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 23%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_container">
 <div class="main_img"><img src="http://hmsholidays.fluidux.in/wp-content/uploads/world/big-img1.jpg" class="bg4" alt=""></div>
 <div class="loader"><img src="http://chimplyimage.appspot.com/images/samples/classic-spinner/animatedCircle.gif" class="loading_img" alt=""></div>
</div>

 <ul class="cs-thumb-list img1">
 <li>
  <a href="#" title="img1"><img src="http://hmsholidays.fluidux.in/wp-content/uploads/world/thumb-img1.jpg"
    alt=""></a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#" title="img2"><img src="http://hmsholidays.fluidux.in/wp-content/uploads/world/thumb-img2.jpg"
    alt=""></a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#" title="img3"><img src="http://hmsholidays.fluidux.in/wp-content/uploads/world/thumb-img3.jpg"
    alt=""></a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#" title="img4"><img src="http://hmsholidays.fluidux.in/wp-content/uploads/world/thumb-img4.jpg" alt=""></a>
 </li>
</ul>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://hmsholidays.fluidux.in/wp-content/themes/hmsHolidays/js/jquery.js'></script>
```